# how to create a narrow centered column in twitter-bootstrap-3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used this code to create a narrow centered column in bootstrap:

```
 <div class="container" style="width:640px!important;max-width:100%!important;">
        <div class="well">content</div>
    </div>
```

how can make it standard and responsive in bootstrap?

Comment: Then why you fixed your width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'make it standard' but the reason your column is not responsive is because you assigned `max-width` and `width` the wrong values. Your code should be as follows:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100% !important; max-width: 640px !important;">
  <div class="well">content</div>
</div>
```